# Toggle Login/Register Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is something wrong with my code. It might be that my javascript is placed in the wrong section of the code. I like to be able to toggle to different login/register page. For example, if i click on login, it should be the login box and if I click on the register, it should be the registration box.

I tried looking at Chrome console, but it doesn't give me any information.

Code: http://jsbin.com/kosunefufe/edit?html,output

Thanks

Chris

Comment: The placement of your scripts which you mentioned does not seem to be the problem, but it is considered better these days to put your javascript in the `head` tag and then apply the `async` attribute so that it does not hold up parsing the rest of the page, but is also not last to load.

Comment: Your JS Bin example has no actual HTML elements for either form (no forms, no links, etc.).